# Getting error while calling class method using PHP

Tags: php, class

I am getting error while calling one class method using PHP. My code is below.

user.php:

```
require_once ('common.php');
$userClass=new CommonUtilFuncs();
$login_code =$userClass->getToken(6);
echo $login_code;
```

common.php:

```
class CommonUtilFuncs{
   function __construct() {

    }
    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }
    public function getToken($length){
        $token = "";
        $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
        $max = strlen($codeAlphabet); // edited
        $crypto=$this->crypto_rand_secure(0, $max - 1);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $token .= $codeAlphabet[$crypto];
        }
        return $token;
    }
    private function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max) {
        $range = $max - $min;
        if ($range < 1)
            return $min; // not so random...
        $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
        $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
        $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
        $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
        do {
            $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
            $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
        } while ($rnd > $range);
        return $min + $rnd;
    }
}
```

Here in `user.php` page I am trying to print the login code  but no result is coming. `The page is not working` error is coming.

Comment: What's error you are getting ?

Comment: @mi6crazyheart : When I am running the file `The page is not working` message is displaying.

Comment: Are you getting any PHP error? If yes, print the error message also.

Comment: No,this message only coming.

Comment: turn on error_reporting. Thats the only way you'll know

Comment: Paste this code ```error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', '1');``` on top of the ```user.php``` file & execute once. If you've any PHP error it'll be visible on the page.

Comment: If you really wrote the above code, you should also know how important it is to have error_reporting on

Comment: @mi6crazyheart : got this `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CommonUtilFuncs::getToken()` error.

Comment: So, it's showing ```getToken()``` method is not exist in that ```CommonUtilFuncs``` object. There is some problem in your ```CommonUtilFuncs``` object creation.

Comment: Are you sure the class `CommonUtilFuncs` is not used somewhere else?

Comment: @mi6crazyheart : But I already have that method inside the class.

Comment: Let me to change the class name and check.

Comment: I just change the class name and it started worked but I think the `crypto_rand_secure` could not called.

Comment: Maybe that class has been overwritten somewhere else.

Comment: The code works fine for me

Comment: @satya in your post you say "`The page is not working` error is coming." however that error isn't shown anywhere in the code provided.

Answer (score -1):

Change file name from

```
common.php
```

to

```
CommonUtilFuncs.php
```

And also change `require_once ('common.php')` to `require_once ('CommonUtilFuncs.php')`;

Comment: The code should still work even the name of the file is different than the name of the class.